# Is this a trick? Or too difficult?

Tags: exam-questions, listening

I am now practicing a TOEFL listening section with a textbook.

Now, given such a kind of information like below,

> Well, I'm a member of the drama club and **we are going to on tour two weeks from now**. We are performing Arthur Miller's "The Death Of a Salesman" at hour other colleges. **I'll be gone the entire week** and I'm afraid I'll miss three classes.

Now the test question is

> How long will the student be gone?

Choices are

> (A) One week
>   (B) Two weeks
>   (c) Three weeks
>   (d) Four weeks

The answer is (A). I heard the question saying **"We are going to on tour two weeks from now."** so, I chose (B). But the text says, (A) is correct because (or only because) there was saying **I'll be gone the entire week**.

Couldn't this question be too difficult or **how do you interpret**? Personally thinking there 2 contradicting information in the passage, at least it seems to me.

Comment: It's a straightforward question. No conflicting information. No tricks. But you might say it has a [red herring](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/red-herring).

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are two errors in your transcription. I think "at hour other colleges" should probably be "at ***our*** other colleges." I also think "we are going to on tour two weeks from now" is either "we are going to **be** on tour two weeks from now," or "we are going on tour two weeks from now," or perhaps "we are going to tour two weeks from now." Whichever it is, they all refer to when the tour starts, so that length of time is not included in the tour.

Comment: I agree with @J.R. about the errors in transcription.  One other possibility: "we are going to go on tour two weeks from now"

Comment: @J.R Thank you for your remarks. As I mentioned at Havey's answer, I bought another new book..this book has only 3+some reputation according to  amazon ( by 24 people ). **I'll be gone the entire week** Yes, I can understand this phrase without any problem, but a phrase for the world wide test? I started to doubt the quality..but again thank you for all of your comments and answers.

Comment: @J.R. I suspect "hour other colleges" is a typo for "*four* other colleges"

Comment: @J.R. This comes from the same book from which I ask about "Up in the stack".

Comment: @Barmar - Could be. I might have been thrown off when the OP said "listening section" – I wondered if there were some audio files on CD or something.

Comment: or, instead of "We are going to on tour", "We are going on tour", just eliminating the "to" (so there is no need for "to go", or "to be")

Comment: I apologize that recording the original content failed. May be due to the copyright infringement stuff. Now, in addition to it, the CD itself is completely broken..........

Comment: Ugh...thank you for editing. I'm a bit confused if there is any more motivations for you to update this when the original CD is no more available...

Comment: What we'd like is for *every* question on the site to be potentially useful to someone else in the future.  Other people can find this post while searching the website, or while search on Google, and they can learn from it.  If we really feel that a particular Q&A will *never* be of use to anyone in the future, we close or delete that question.  So if this is a valid question for the site, we'd like to edit it to fix any errors for the sake of future users, even if you no longer have the CD yourself.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

"We are going on tour two weeks from now" means "it is arranged that our tour starts two weeks from now". This provides information about how far in the future the departure is. "I'll be gone the entire week" provides information about the duration of the speaker's absence. There is no conflict. A person who correctly understands (comprehends) the information given will see only one correct answer.

Comment: Actually according to Amazon's comments the reputation is not so good about this book and even one says it is full of typo and so I bought a new book. **go to on tour** , it this grammatical?

Comment: @KentaroTomono "going to on tour" is not grammatical, it should be "going to go on tour", "going on tour" or possibly "going to tour". With "go" instead of "going" you would have to say "go on tour".

Answer (score 18):

It is a clear question, and there is enough information to answer it.

> I'm going on tour two weeks from now

This tell you when she is leaving. The tour will start after two weeks.

> I'll be gone the whole week.

This tells you how long someone will be gone. It tells you explicitly that she will be gone for *one* whole week.

Comprehension questions often have this kind of "red herring".

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following and their interpretations:

> I'm going on tour two weeks from now.  I'll be gone the whole week.

and

> I'm going on tour two years from now.  I'll be gone one week.

In both cases the first sentence says how long it will be until the tour starts, and the second sentence states how long it will last (once it starts).  A native speaker would never assume the second phrasing implied that someone was going to be gone for two years.

If anything, the phrasing that might cause confusion is "... gone the whole week" rather than "... gone a whole week."  Using the phrasing "the whole week" implies that there is a "correct" way to divide time up into weeks.  Most typically this means a week starting on Sunday and ending on Saturday, but sometimes it refers to Monday through Friday (excludes weekends).  In this context, both meanings yield the same effect: they will miss a week's worth of classes.